# 3D or 4D interpolate to find the corrsponding values based on 4 column of variables

Tags: matlab, 3d, interpolation, 4d

I'm trying to find out whether if its possible to find/interpolate to calculate the corresponding values from this set of variables

```
+-------------+-------------+------+------+
|      x      |      y      |  z   |  g   |
+-------------+-------------+------+------+
| 150.8385804 | 183.7613678 | 0.58 | 2    |
| 171.0745381 | 231.7033081 | 2    | 0.58 |
| 179.1394672 | 244.5019837 | 0.8  | 0.8  |
| 149.1849453 | 180.7103271 | 0.8  | 2    |
| 162.5648017 | 212.8121033 | 2    | 0.8  |
| 141.1687115 | 163.4759979 | 0.8  | 3    |
| 140.7505385 | 162.7905884 | 0.9  | 3    |
| 148.1461022 | 180.5486908 | 1.8  | 1.6  |
| 147.1552106 | 178.7599182 | 2    | 1.6  |
+-------------+-------------+------+------+
```

What would be the corresponding z and g for x=143 and y=179? I do have access to matlab if anyone can suggest a code for it.

Here is the MATLAB syntax to load the above data into your workspace:

```
X = [150.8385804 171.0745381 179.1394672 149.1849453 162.5648017 141.1687115 140.7505385 148.1461022 147.1552106].';
Y = [183.7613678 231.7033081 244.5019837 180.7103271 212.8121033 163.4759979 162.7905884 180.5486908 178.7599182].';
Z = [0.58 2 0.8 0.8 2 0.8 0.9 1.8 2].';
G = [2 0.58 0.8 2 0.8 3 3 1.6 1.6].';
```

Comment: I have added in the MATLAB syntax to load that data into your workspace.  Taking your table and inputting it into MATLAB was a royal pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scatteredInterpolant` to do this for you.  `scatteredInterpolant` is used to perform interpolation on a **scattered dataset**, which is basically what you have.  Actually, you can do it twice: Once for `z` and once for `g`.  You specify `x` and `y` as key / control points with the corresponding `z` and `g` output points.  `scatteredInterpolant` will create an object for you, and you can specify custom `x` and `y` values for each of the `z` and `g` `scatteredInterpolants` and it will give you an interpolated answer.  The default interpolation method is **linear**.  As such, you'd specify `x=143` and `y=179` and figure out what the output `z` and `g` are.

In other words:

```
X = [150.8385804 171.0745381 179.1394672 149.1849453 162.5648017 141.1687115 140.7505385 148.1461022 147.1552106].';
Y = [183.7613678 231.7033081 244.5019837 180.7103271 212.8121033 163.4759979 162.7905884 180.5486908 178.7599182].';
Z = [0.58 2 0.8 0.8 2 0.8 0.9 1.8 2].';
G = [2 0.58 0.8 2 0.8 3 3 1.6 1.6].';

%// Create scatteredInterpolant
Zq = scatteredInterpolant(X, Y, Z);
Gq = scatteredInterpolant(X, Y, G);

%// Figure out interpolated values
zInterp = Zq(143, 179);
gInterp = Gq(143, 179);
```

Comment: Thank you very much..It works but its off my a miles away, guess I need more data points.

Comment: @user3798722 - You're very welcome.  Yeah I was wondering why the values were way way off.  I didn't put those values in my answer because I thought maybe those were the kind of values you were looking for, but yes you do indeed need more points.